# Prove this inequality $\sum _{cyc}\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{3b^2+bc}}\ge \frac{3}{2}$

Tags: inequality, radicals, fractions, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, holder-inequality

For $a,b,c>0$ and $ab+bc+ca=3$. Prove that $$P=\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{3b^2+bc}}+\frac{b^2}{\sqrt{3c^2+ca}}+\frac{c^2}{\sqrt{3a^2+ab}}\ge \frac{3}{2}$$

---

By AM-GM $\frac{a^3}{2\sqrt{3ab^2+abc}}+\frac{a^3}{2\sqrt{3ab^2+abc}}+\frac{3ab^2+abc}{16}\ge 3\sqrt[3]{\frac{a^6}{64}}=\frac{3a^2}{4}$

$\Rightarrow P+\sum _{cyc}\frac{3ab^2+abc}{16}\ge \frac{3\left(a^2+b^2+c^2\right)}{4}\ge \frac{9}{4}$

Need prove $\sum _{cyc}\frac{3ab^2+abc}{16}\ge \frac{9}{4}-\frac{3}{2}=\frac{3}{4}$

Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Holder
$$\left(\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}
{3b^2+bc}\right)^2\sum_{cyc}a^2(3b^2+bc)\geq(a^2+b^2+c^2)^3.$$
Thus, it remains to prove that
$$4(a^2+b^2+c^2)^3\geq3(ab+ac+bc)\sum_{cyc}a^2(3b^2+bc),$$
which is true because
$$a^2+b^2+c^2\geq ab+ac+bc$$ and
$$4(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2\geq12\sum_{cyc}a^2b^2=3\sum_{cyc}4a^2b^2\geq3\sum_{cyc}(3a^2b^2+a^2bc).$$
Done!

Another way.
$$a+b+c=\sqrt{(a+b+c)^2}=\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}(a^2+2bc)}\geq\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}(ab+2bc)}=3.$$
Thus, by AM-GM and Holder we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{3b^2+bc}}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{4a^2}{2\sqrt{4b(3b+c)}}\geq\sum_{cyc}\frac{4a^2}{4b+3b+c}=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}\frac{4a^3}{7ab+ac}\geq\frac{4(a+b+c)^3}{3\sum\limits_{cyc}(7ab+ac)}=\frac{(a+b+c)^3}{18}\geq\frac{27}{18}=\frac{3}{2}.$$

Comment: first ano :why $4(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2\geq12\sum_{cyc}a^2b^2$

Comment: @Word Shallow It's $(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2\geq3(a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2)$ or $\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2-b^2)^2\geq0$.